# How to programmatically generate square images with users' initials?

Tags: image, bitmap, imagemagick, graphic

I want to create images for users, similar to what google does on gmail for android, as shown in this screenshot: http://blog.brightwavemarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/gmail_for_android_4.5.png

I took a look at using ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/) from the command line but I'm hoping there are simpler options out there I could use instead.

What I need to do:
- specify image size
- specify background color
- specify a pair of letters for the foreground, choose their color, and make them 80% of the width of the square
- anti-alias the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from this command:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:#A02B2B -pointsize 70 -fill White -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 'AZ'" output.jpg
```

It genarates a square of specified size(`-size 100x100`) and color (`xc:#A02B2B`) filling it with letters (`'AZ'`) of specified color (`-fill White`).

This is command's output:

[image]

Comment: I ran that command and the output looks similar but is aliased. How can I anti-alias it?

Might it be related to the following warnings I get?

    convert: unable to read font `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n019003l.pfb' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1123.
    convert: unable to read font `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n019003l.pfb' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1123.

Comment: @lowellk Maybe the problem is related with the warnings: according to [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/) page Imagemagick should apply antialiasing by default